# Automation of Google Sheets (Google Scripts) so that when cell date is in the past the row is moved into another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to set an automation using the code below that moves entire rows based on a row's specific cell value (date) being in the past. The column containing that date is "L" if that helps, I am unsure where to use this if necessary, is this within the `getDataRange` function? The date information I am using is in the current format: `1/25/2021 19:30:00`

When I run the code below it gives me the 'Execution Completed' notice but it doesn't appear to be moving the rows across into the destination sheet (`Auction Results`).

To provide further context the Original sheet is called `Collecting Cars - Live` and today's date is saved in the sheet `App Rules` in B1.

```
function MovetoPastShows2() {
   function MovetoPastShows2() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Auctions - Live'); 
   var rg=sh.getDataRange();
   var vA=rg.getValues();
   var today=new Date(ss.getSheetByName('App Rules').getRange('B1').getValue()).valueOf();
   var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Auction Results'); 
   var d=0;
   for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
     if (new Date(vA[i][2]).valueOf()<=today) {
       dsh.appendRow(vA[i])
       sh.deleteRow(i+1-d);
       d++;
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Issue:**

You have a `MovetoPastShows2` function inside another `MovetoPastShows2` function.

- The **inside** `MovetoPastShows2()` is never executed and therefore the code within that function is **never** executed as well.
- You only execute the **outer** `MovetoPastShows2()` where its only job is to **define** another function with the same name. It does not execute the actual code inside that inner function though.
- It is not a good idea to have 2 functions with the same name. Although that is not the issue here, it is a general recommendation.

### **Solution:**

Remove the outer `MovetoPastShows2()`:

```
function MovetoPastShows2() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Auctions - Live'); 
   var rg=sh.getDataRange();
   var vA=rg.getValues();
   var today=new Date(ss.getSheetByName('App Rules').getRange('B1').getValue()).valueOf();
   var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Auction Results'); 
   var d=0;
   for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
     if (new Date(vA[i][2]).valueOf()<=today) {
       dsh.appendRow(vA[i])
       sh.deleteRow(i+1-d);
       d++;
      }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Marios, that makes sense. I have just made that change as you suggested, but still cannot get it to work as expected but no errors are flagged in google scripts. It still seems to say 'Execution Completed'.

Comment: true that the sheet 'Auctions - Live' has no contents. Although even after adding a header row thus giving it 1 row of contents and running it again still no luck.

Comment: @BenWillis then `if (new Date(vA[i][2]).valueOf()<=today)` does not evaluate to `true`...  Are you sure you have a `date` in column C of the `Auctions - Live` sheet but also `App Rules` `B1` contains a date as well? it would make sense to `console.log(today)` and `new Date(vA[0][2]).valueOf()` before the `for` loop just to make sure the data is correct.

Comment: No I don't have a date in Column C of Auctions - Live, the date value is in Column L not C, where do I change this?

Comment: replace `new Date(vA[i][2])` with `new Date(vA[i][11])` and try again. @BenWillis

Comment: Ahh I have figured it out, I had 2 instead of 11. 2 representing Column C and 11 representing Column L. Thank you! It is working now. Is it possible to automate this function to run as soon as a date in this sheet in the past?